# Properties of $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)+x+2$ vs $g(x)=\cosh x+\sinh x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, contest-math

This is from an MCQ contest.

> Consider the two functions: $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)+x+2$ et $g(x)=ch(x)+sh(x)$.
>
> The real number $c$ such that: $(f^{-1})'(2)=g(c)$
>
> - $1]$ $c=-1$
> - $2]$ $c=0$
> - $3]$ $c=1$
> - $4]$ None of the above statements is correct

My Thoughts:

note that :
$$\left(f^{-1}\right)^\prime (y)=\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)}.$$
and 
$$ch(x)+sh(x)=e^x$$

but first we should check $f$ it's invertible or not

indeed,
$f$ is strictly increasing continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ since 
$$f'(x)=\dfrac{(x+1)^{2}}{x^2+1}\geq 0$$

then $f$ is invertible thus has inverse function

$$f(x)=y\iff x=f^{-1}(x) \\
\ln(1+x^2)+x+2=y
$$
i'm stuck here

Any help will be apprecited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track.  Note that

$$\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}=\left.\frac{y^2+1}{(y+1)^2}\right|_{y=f^{-1}(x)}$$

Now, when $f^{-1}(2)=y$, $\log (1+y^2)+y=0\implies y=0$.  So, we have $f^{-1}(2)=0$ and this means that

$$\left.\frac{df^{-1}(x)}{dx}\right|_{x=2}=\left.\frac{y^2+1}{(y+1)^2}\right|_{y=f^{-1}(2)=0}=1$$

Since $g(x)=e^x$, then if $g(c)=1$, $c=0$.  The answer is, therefore

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{c=0}$$

Comment: Dr.MV  Well-explained

Comment: @Educ Thank you! Please to hear.

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{-1}(2)=t$$
$$f(t)=2$$
$$\ln(1+t^2)+t+2=2$$
Should I continue?

Comment: how did you know that $f^{-1}(2)=t$

Comment: One can call the $f^{-1}(2)$ whatever he wants :) . Wouldn't it be useful to find this value for finding $c$ ?

Comment: For taking derivative you need to know the value where you taking it. So  you have to find $t$    or whatever you call it.

Comment: Mihail  yes i see